# Can't Install Netlify cms plugin Gatsby

Tags: npm, plugins, content-management-system, gatsby, netlify

i tried to install netlifycms to my gatsby-config.js but its show error unreachable. how i can fix it?

my github repo https://github.com/muhammadizzuddin/portofolio/blob/main/gatsby-config.js

ERROR

There was a problem loading plugin "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms". Perhaps you need to install its package?
Use --verbose to see actual error.

ERROR

Failed to resolve gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms unreachable

Error: unreachable
please help me.

```
 ERROR

There was a problem loading plugin "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms". Perhaps you need to install its package?
Use --verbose to see actual error.


 ERROR

Failed to resolve gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms unreachable



  Error: unreachable

  - load.ts:144 resolvePlugin
    [portofolio]/[gatsby]/src/bootstrap/load-plugins/load.ts:144:11

  - index.js:37 resolveTheme
    [portofolio]/[gatsby]/src/bootstrap/load-themes/index.js:37:29

  - index.js:115
    [portofolio]/[gatsby]/src/bootstrap/load-themes/index.js:115:30

  - util.js:16 tryCatcher
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23

  - reduce.js:166 Object.gotValue
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/reduce.js:166:18

  - reduce.js:155 Object.gotAccum
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/reduce.js:155:25

  - util.js:16 Object.tryCatcher
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23

  - promise.js:547 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:547:31

  - promise.js:604 Promise._settlePromise
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:604:18

  - promise.js:649 Promise._settlePromise0
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:649:10

  - promise.js:729 Promise._settlePromises
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:729:18

  - async.js:93 _drainQueueStep
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:93:12

  - async.js:86 _drainQueue
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:86:9

  - async.js:102 Async._drainQueues
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:102:5

  - async.js:15 Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate]
    [portofolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:15:14

  - timers.js:462 processImmediate
    internal/timers.js:462:21


not finished open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.591s
```

Comment: Have you tried changing quotation in gatsby-config to backticks like this: `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms` ? Did you run npm install netlify-cms-app gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms ?

Answer (score 0):

The link is broken so I've assumed that the working one is https://github.com/muhammadizzuddin/my-blog.

You just need to add the `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms` to your `package.json` by running

```
npm i gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms
```

This will update your `package.json` file and will notify Netlify which packages needs to be installed when deploying.